# Socket Asynchronous C# recebendo mais de uma mensagem ao mesmo tempo

Tags: c#, c++, socket, tcp, assincronismo

Estou desenvolvendo uma Dll C# que trabalha com Socket TCP Asynchronous para o desenvolvimento de algumas ferramentas que estou trabalhando, o problema aparece quando o cliente recebe muitas mensagem em um curto período, neste caso as mensagens são em JSON, sendo assim, o servidor me envia somente uma mensagem JSON por ver, mas o cliente recebe 2 ou 3 juntas, causando uma Exception ao tentar transformar o JSON em Objeto. Sendo que, se eu mandar o servidor mandar uma mensagem a cada segundo, tudo ocorre bem, mas meu sistema depende de mais mensagens por segundo.
OBS: O Servidor é feito em C++ com QT.

**CLIENTE:**

```
    public void connect(Action<Message> callback, string ip, int porta){
        this.callback = callback;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.porta = porta;
        try{
            this.ipadress = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Parse (this.ip), this.porta);
            this.client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
            this.client.BeginConnect (this.ipadress, new AsyncCallback (ConectCallback), null);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            this.conected = false;
            lastExeception = ex;
        }
    }
    void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult IA){
        String json_string = "";
        if (isConnected ()) {
            try {
                int received = client.EndReceive (IA);
                Array.Resize (ref _buffer, received);
                json_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (_buffer);

                Console.WriteLine(json_string);

                Message msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message> (json_string);
                callback_sender (msg);

                Array.Resize (ref _buffer, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                if (isConnected ())
                    client.BeginReceive (_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback (ReceiveCallback), null);
            } catch (JsonException erro) {
                lastExeception = erro;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                lastExeception = ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

**SERVIDOR:**

```
void MyClient::readyRead() {
   qDebug() << "MyClient::readyRead()";
   QString msg = socket->readAll();
   qDebug() << msg;
   socket->write(msg.toUtf8());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema do seguinte modo, como eu sempre recebia vários JSONs juntos, eu verificava se havia o final e o inicio das chaves, se sim, transformava o JSON simples em uma List, e assim consegui receber tudo sem Exception.

```
void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult IA){
        String json_string = "";
        if (isConnected ()) {
            try {
                int received = client.EndReceive (IA);
                Array.Resize (ref _buffer, received);
                json_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (_buffer);

                if(json_string.Contains("}{")){ // verifica se existe mais de um JSON na String
                    json_string = json_string.Replace("}{","},{"); // transforma em Array de JSON
                }
                json_string = "["+json_string+"]"; // finaliza o array com colchetes para não ocorrer erro

                List<Message> msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>> (json_string); // Transforma a string JSON e lista de Objeto
                foreach(Message m in msg){ // pega todos os objetos da lista
                    callback_sender(m);
                }

                Array.Resize (ref _buffer, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                if (isConnected ())
                    client.BeginReceive (_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback (ReceiveCallback), null);
            } catch (JsonException erro) {
                lastExeception = erro;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                lastExeception = ex;
            }
        }
    }
```